# j2me powerpoint application

Tags: java-me, powerpoint

I want to create a simple mobile application which can give a slideshow from a Microsoft PowerPoint (PPT) file and has basic text editing functions....

Is there any API that I can use?  How can I do ths?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no public API for this purpose.

Use [PowerPoint file format description](http://www.microsoft.com/interop/docs/officebinaryformats.mspx) to implement your own rendering engine for PowerPoint files on J2ME platform.